# Python's "re" module not working?

Tags: python, string, get

I'm using Python's "re" module as follows:

```
request = get("http://www.allmusic.com/album/warning-mw0000106792")
print re.findall('<hgroup>(.*?)</hgroup>', request)
```

All I'm doing is getting the HTML of [this site](http://www.allmusic.com/album/warning-mw0000106792), and looking for this particular snippet of code:

```
<hgroup>
    <h3 class="album-artist">
        <a href="http://www.allmusic.com/artist/green-day-mn0000154544">Green Day</a>        </h3>

    <h2 class="album-title">
        Warning        </h2>
</hgroup>
```

However, it continues to print an empty array. Why is this? Why can't re.findall find this snippet?

Comment: What about `<hgroup><hgroup></hgroup></hgroup>`? What should that match?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The HTML you are parsing is on multiple lines.  You need to pass the `re.DOTALL` flag to `findall` like this:

```
print re.findall('<hgroup>(.*?)</hgroup>', request, re.DOTALL)
```

This allows `.` to match newlines, and returns the correct output.

@jsalonen is right, of course, that parsing HTML with regex is a tricky problem.  However, in small cases like this especially for a one-off script I'd say it's acceptable.

Comment: Seriously guys. Regexps for HTML? It may work once or twice, but in the end you are bound to fail: regular expressions are for regular languages, which HTML isn't.

Comment: @jsalonen, for subset of html it's fine. See for instance the second answer you linked

Comment: Sometimes it may work, but its really really bad engineering practice. Also, it's just as simple to use an actual HTML parser. So why not do that?

Comment: @jsalonen I'm well aware of the problems that come with parsing HTML using regexs.  But for such a small problem(especially one that seems to be in a one-off script) I'd say that it's fine.  I personally find `BeautifulSoup` to be significantly more time consuming than writing a small regex.  However, when things become more complicated I always switch to proper HTML parsing.

Comment: @NolenRoyalty I just tried this, but it didn't seem to make a differen; I'm still getting empty arrays.

Comment: @Sim I forgot that you also need the `DOTALL` flag to let `.` match `\n`.  I've updated my answer.  And on second thought, you don't actually need `MULTILINE` after all.  My mistake.

Comment: @NolenRoyalty I can definitely see your point: When quickly hacking things up, it obviously makes sense not to waste time on overengineering. What I'm arguing is that regexps aren't even that much easier. With a good HTML parser the total number of lines is not that different from a hacky regexp solution.

Answer (score 7):

`re` module is not broken. What you are likely encountering is the fact that not all HTML cannot be easily matched with simple regexps.

Instead, try parsing your HTML with an actual HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

request = get("http://www.allmusic.com/album/warning-mw0000106792")
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content)
print soup.findAll('hgroup')
```

Or alternatively, with [pyquery](http://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/):

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

d = pq(url='http://www.allmusic.com/album/warning-mw0000106792')
print d('hgroup')
```

Comment: For some reason I remembered `BeautifulSoup` taking significantly more effort than this.  It was probably just my inexperience using it at the time.  I'm surprised at how easy this solution is.  +1