# Regex multiline- How to grab a portion of a page source

Tags: python, regex

Sorry if this question has been brought to you before, but I find the python regex documentation quite hard to understand mainly due to the lack of examples. 
I want to grab a block of the page source to be later parsed again. For example:

```
    <div id="viewed"><div class="shortstory-block">

    <div class="shortstoey-block-image">
        <a href="...."><img src="/uploads/posts/cov.jpg" alt="instance 1"/></a>
        <span class="format"><a href="http://www..../">something</a></span>
    </div>

    <a href="http://....."><span class="shortstory-block-title" style="text-decoration:none !important;">
        Something
    </span>
    </a>

</div><div class="shortstory-block">

    <div class="shortstoey-block-image">
        <a href="...."><img src="/uploads/posts/cov.jpg" alt="something 2"/></a>
        <span class="format"><a href="http://www.website/xfsearch/smth/">something</a></span>
    </div>

    <a href="http://web.html"><span class="shortstory-block-title" style="text-decoration:none !important;">
        Something
    </span>
    </a>
 </div>
  (* x times)
     <div id="rated">....
```

I have all the page source in a variable (html_source) and I want to define another variable with only this block of code (between div id="viewed" and div id="rated"). I want to grab everything despite any \n or \r that I can find between the two instances.

Can someone point me in the right direction (the regex expression)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The right direction is to use an html parser.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with btoueg. If you want a quick solution, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) useful. It's pretty awesome.

Comment: @user2574761 The quick solution is to use a parser that models the language you want to parse already, instead of trying to write, from scratch, such a parser using a formalism that does not fit the language you want to parse at all. (On accounts of HTML being a prime example of a language that's **not** regular.)

Comment: @user2574761 The failure mode #2 is trying to do everything in a single regexp where the result you want is in one of the capture groups. It's frequently better to just search for a bunch of different patterns and then do the rest with good old substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are indeed just trying to find something between two elements of text that you can use the following regex:

```
import re

with open('yourfile') as fin:
    page_source = fin.read()

start_text = re.escape('<div id="viewed">')
until_text = re.escape('<div id="rated">')
match_text = re.search('{}(.*?){}'.format(start_text, until_text), page_source, flags=re.DOTALL)
if match_text:
    print match_text.group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `re.DOTALL` flag makes . match any character.  Without that flag, it won't match newlines.

(DOTALL can also be spelled `(?s)` in the regexp itself.)

For a similar question, with code samples and better ways to do this, see:
[Python's "re" module not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776670/pythons-re-module-not-working/17776699)